# Pop UIViewController from UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to pop my `ViewController` from `TabBar` which is pushed from that `ViewController` for `Logout` feature in My Application,I put code for that but that only pop on `tabbar`.not in my first `ViewController`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. edit it and explain in proper detail.

Comment: in My App when user login i used tabbar controller now from that I want to add logout button when user press on it I want First Login screen.and exit from tabbar controller.

Comment: IS it your view controller structure: navigationcontroller > loginviewcontroller > tabbarcontroller ?

Comment: yes,now from tabbarcontoller I want to pop my loginviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your logout button action method

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
LoginVC *viewController = [[LoginVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginVC" bundle:nil];
NSArray *array = @[viewController];
[appdelegate.navController setViewControllers:array];
[appdelegate.tabbarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[[appdelegate tabbarController] removeFromParentViewController];
NSLog(@"array - > %@",array);
[appdelegate.window setRootViewController:appdelegate.navController];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have following structure

> Window - UINavigationController - (LoginViewController) -
>   UITabBarController - (VC,VC)

This would work

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` for popping the viewController into root viewController

Comment: This would only work if the current viewController is in the stack of navigationController which is added as the rootViewController of window.